# AngularJS : ui-grid field with a concatenation of two fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need a column in ui-grid which is a concatenation of two fields,say 'name' and 'address'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this approach?

### controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [
             {name: "Moroni", address: test1},
                     {name: "Tiancum", address: test2},
                         {name: "Jacob", address: test3},
                         {name: "Nephi", address: test4},
                         {name: "Enos", address: test5 }];

        angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(row){
          row.getNameAndAddress = function(){
            return this.name + '-' + this.address;
          }
        });

    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
                     {field:'address', displayName:'Address'},
                     {field: 'getNameAndAddress()', displayName: 'Name and address'},
                     ]
        };
});
```

### html

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working example.

```
$scope.myData = [
                   { fname: "Roger", lname: "Binny", age: 50 },
                   { fname: "Smith",lname:"kevin", age: 34 }
                 ];

angular.forEach($scope.myData, function (row) {
    row.getFullName = function () {
        return this.fname + '-' + this.lname;
    }
});

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'fname', displayName: 'First Name' },
                 { field: 'lname', displayName: 'Last Name' },
                 { field: 'getFullName()', displayName: 'Full Name' },
                { field: 'age', displayName: 'Age' },
    ]
};

  <div class="ngGridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

[image]